# How do I add external JS files to my Zurb Foundation 6.4 project (webpack)?

Tags: javascript, webpack, zurb-foundation

I created a new Foundation project using npm and I need to add a [lightbox plugin](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/). Adding an external JS file to the previous version of Foundation was as simple as linking it in the config.yml file. The new version of Foundation uses the module bundler Webpack which I am unfamiliar with. I tried following [these instructions](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/53526#comment_38968) but did not have any success and ended up with a Jquery is not defined error.

I dropped the minified lightbox plugin in the /lib directory and tried linking the file in the app.js and config.yml files but also had no success. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve adding:

```
window.jQuery = $;
```

and call the file externally as you're doing.
That's the quick solution.

To add to the webpack build it's something I'm still unsure (if the plugin is not and exported module by default)